# Как расставить знаки препинания в этом предложении? (3)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Я ученик 5 класса школы №1344 города Москвы Иван Иванов.

Comment: Запятые здесь не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Ориентируясь на общее правило, мы, конечно же, говорим, что в этом предложении не должно быть никаких знаков.

> **8.** Если подлежащее выражено *личным местоимением*, а сказуемое — формой именительного падежа существительного, тире между ними обычно не ставится...

*Я ученик 5 класса школы №1344 города Москвы Иван Иванов.*
Поверь же мне, **я ученик** Парижского университета, я друг Оже. [А. К. Виноградов. Черный консул (1932)]
Мне семнадцать лет, **я ученик** десятого класса. [Валерий Аграновский. Вторая древнейшая. Беседы о журналистике (1976-1999)]

Но при логическом подчеркивании между подлежащим и сказуемым ставится тире, а *Иван Иванов* в этом случае отделяется запятой.
*Я — ученик 5 класса школы №1344 города Москвы, Иван Иванов.*
**Я ― ученик** восьмого класса и начинающий поэт. [Ю. К. Олеша. Книга прощания (1930-1959)]
«Смертельно бледный Вознесенский говорил: «**Я ― ученик** Пастернака». [Андрей Вознесенский. На виртуальном ветру (1998)]

Вот пример разного пунктуационного оформления у одного автора, В. Ф. Пановой:
*До вас, полагаю, дошло, что я ученик Себастиана.

Надорвитесь, лопните, я ― ученик Себастиана, все равно пущу время вперед!*

[Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91#pp91)

Comment: Ой, как же мне не нравится твой второй вариант! Особенно запятая. Прости, Рим!

Comment: «твой второй вариант» — Где бы его увидеть?